# Using AspectJ to set the value of an annotated method parameter

Tags: java, aspectj

I imagine a method

```
public void fooMethod(Object param1, @SetupParam Object param2){
    // ... do stuff
}
```

That I want to call without the need of having to set param2

```
fooMethod("param1");
```

but having it magically setup in an advise. 
I am currently working with this code (simplified)

```
@Around("@annotation(com.example.SetupParam)")
public Object setupParam(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    args[1] = "setup";
    return pjp.proceed(args);
}
```

but I need to call that method every time with

```
fooMethod("param1", null);
```

So I want to get rid of the null parameter. I am not using @Autowiring since the second parameter inside the method is always instantiated with different values.

Comment: Add a method `public void fooMethod(Object param1) {fooMethod(param1, null);}` to the class and you can just call fooMethod("param1").

Comment: but how to annotate the second parameter, since it might not always be the second one, parameter list may vary

Answer (score 0):

I think Your pointcut definiition is wrong. What You need is `@args` definition with annotation inside. This matches methods whose arguments are annotated with defined annotation (as You described in question) your advice should look similar (haven't tested it) to

```
@Around("@args(.., com.example.SetupParam))")
```

note that `..` means any number of arguments of any type.

Unfortunately, `@args` supports [**at most one .. wildcard**](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/printable.html#runtime-type-matching-and-context-exposure), so as long as You decide on having those annotated arguments either at the start or at the end of your argument list, You should be fine.